# How to make if statement always returns true for Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

In one of our rails (3.2) modules, there is conditional `include`:

```
include UsersHelper if find_config_const('allow_sales_manage_customer_login') == 'true'
```

Here the `find_config_const` is a method searching a table to find the value of `allow_sales_manage_customer_login`. When testing with rspec (ver 2.14), Module `UserHelper` needs to be `include` and therefore `find_config_const('allow_sales_manage_customer_login') == 'true'` should always return true. FactoryGirl does not work here because the entry created by FactoryGirl is loaded AFTER `include` and `find_config_const('allow_sales_manage_customer_login') == 'true'` is false. Is there a way we can make `find_config_const('allow_sales_manage_customer_login') == 'true'` always returns true for rspec (ver 2.14)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to stub the method by using #stub or #should_receive.

Can you tell me where the find_config_const method is defined?

Suppose it is defined in SomeHelper. You could do:

```
SomeHelper.any_instance.stub(:find_config_const).with('allow_sales_manage_customer_login').and_return(true)
```

Comment: @@spiria, find_config_const is defined in Authen::AuthenUtility. We put the following in before(:each) : Authen::AuthenUtility.any_instance.stub(:find_config_const).with('allow_sales_manage_customer_login').and_return(true).  There is NoMethod error saying undefined any_instance  for Authen::AuthenUtility:Module. Anything we missed?

Comment: Can you try this?

Authen::AuthenUtility.should_receive(:find_config_const).with('allow_sales_ma‌​nage_customer_login').and_return(true)